# Is it a "visit by someone" or "from someone" when they visit?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should I use?

My college friends visited me at my new apartment and we took some pictures of the place. I wanted to create an album in Facebook but I don't know which one is the correct title to use.

> - A visit by my college friends
> - A visit from my college friends

Answer (score 3):

> A visit from my college friends

is the correct title to use. When someone visits you, you receive a visit **from** them. We would use **by** with the passive voice:

> I was visited by my college friends.